# Send some data to contact from app (Objective-C, Swift)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Is there any way I can send some data to contact from contacts app? for example some string or integer? E.g. I have an app, when user open it the app shows all contacts from Contacts app. and when he tap one of the contact the app must send data to the persons phone. Must I do it with web service or there is any way to do it without web service?

P.S. sorry for my english!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this using built-in iOS libraries without invoking a UI. You can send an SMS message using the `MFMessageComposeViewController` class. That displays a UI to the user. If I remember correctly you can prepopulate the view with the content you want to send, but the user can edit it.

Likewise there is the `MFMailComposeViewController` for sending email, with or without attachments.

If you want to send data to another user without displaying a UI to the user you will need to either use a webservice or come up with your own system (involving a server you manage, a TCP socket connection between copies of your app running on both devices, or some other custom development)

Comment: Tnx, for u response. in this way I must go with WebSocket over TCP.